# Angular post not providing request body as expected

Tags: javascript, spring, angular, http-post

My first solo Angular app...

I'm attempting to post to my brand new web service and am using the following code:

```
  headers = new HttpHeaders(
    {'Content-Type':'text/plain'}
  );
  loginUrl = "http://localhost:8093/login";

  login(credentials): Observable<String> {
    const body = new HttpParams()
      .set('payload', 'testing...');

    let bodyValue = body.toString()
    return this.http.post<String>(this.loginUrl, body,{headers: this.headers})
  }
```

And my spring boot app is throwing an exception because, while it's getting a post, the payload parameter is missing from the request.

I opened the web developer network panel in my firefox browser and have the following view:

[image]

At first, I thought it was a mis-config on my spring side, but I ran a curl:

```
  curl --data "payload=testing" http://localhost:8093/login
```

and this went into my web service just fine. So there's something about the way Angular is coding my parameters.

I found this page: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19535, but not sure it's related.

Comment: Can you show how you assign `loginUrl`? the second param to `http.post` is the content body - not URL params

Comment: @pixelbits Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter to `http.post` is the content body. You can pass URL parameters this way:

```
const urlParams = new HttpParams()
  .set('payload', 'testing...');

 return this.http.post<String>(`${this.loginUrl}?${urlParams}`, '',{headers: this.headers});
```

If you want to pass the url parms into the body, then:

```
  login(credentials): Observable<String> {
    const body = new HttpParams()
      .set('payload', 'testing...');

    let bodyValue = body.toString()
    return this.http.post<String>(this.loginUrl, bodyValue,{headers: this.headers})
  }
```

Comment: Interesting. This seems to be working. The thing I want to make sure of is that this won't be visible to the outside world. When I switch to https I want to make sure that the username and password are encrypted.